# in gdi, how to clear the background color of DC. so, the drawed text will show no background color

Tags: winapi, gdi

when i draw text use DC, it always show an backgournd color which is diffrent from window's background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
```

This will prevent the text-drawing functions (and some others) from drawing a background. `SetBkMode(hdc, OPAQUE)` will switch back to opaque mode.